# Can't Open Unfound File: GPG key retrieval failed error

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I'm trying to install the `anaconda` package on a Linux box with the RHEL Server Release 7.2 Operating System with the command `sudo yum install anaconda`. It gives me the error: `GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6`.

I've tried solving the issue by using the command `sudo yum install epel-release`, but that doesn't fix the error. I believe the file `rpm` should look for when installing anaconda is `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7` instead of `RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6` since I'm using RHEL 7 instead of RHEL 6.

What commands can I use so that I can install `anaconda` on my machine without errors?

Similar issues were found on other operating systems here:
1) https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/33688/gpg-key-retrieval-failed-errno-14-curl37-couldnt-open-file-etcpkirpm-gpgrpm-gpg-key-fedora-i386/ 
2) https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7439/gpg-key-retrieval-failed/

Similar issues were found on RHEL OS here: 
1) https://serverfault.com/questions/525958/redhat-yum-install-gpg-key-retrieval-failed

Answer (score 4):

`sudo yum install --nogpgcheck anaconda`

Comment: Why did this receive a down vote when it was the exact command that allowed me to install the anaconda package? This is the right answer, and will be green checked shortly as the right answer.

Comment: Sadly it wasn't accepted but sudo yum install --nogpgcheck <package> fixes this.